# Usar static Closures ou Closures no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, instanciar-objeto, closures

A partir do PHP 5.4, as `Closures` (Ou `funções anônimas`), quando declaradas dentro do contexto de um método da classe (que não sejam os métodos estáticos), automaticamente herdam para "dentro dela" o `$this` como referência da classe que a contém.

Exemplo:

```
class StackOverflow
{
    protected $array = ['stack', 'overflow', 'portugues'];

    public function testClosure($string)
    {      
        $callback = function()
        {
            print_r($this);

            /*
                StackOverflow Object
                (
                    [array:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stack
                            [1] => overflow
                            [2] => portugues
                        )
                )
            */

            return 'stack';
        };

        return preg_replace_callback('/stick/', $callback, $string);
    }
}

(new StackOverflow)->testClosure('stick overflow');
```

Como visto no exemplo, quando fazemos o `print_r($this)`, retornará a instância atual da classe `StackOverflow`.

Porém, se fizemos uma pequena alteração e adicionarmos a palavra-chave `static` antes da declaração da função anônima, a variável `$this` não "importa" a instância da classe `StackOverflow` lá para dentro:

```
public function testClosure($string)
{
      // Closure static não importa o $this para o Escopo
      $callback = static function()
      {
          print_r($this); // Undefined variable: this
          return 'stack';
      };

      return preg_replace_callback('/stick/', $callback, $string);
}
```

Como visto no exemplo, estou utilizando a função `preg_replace_callback` para poder fazer alteração em uma *string* através de uma *regex*. Ou seja, eu não preciso de ter o `$this` propriamente dentro da classe, mas somente quero utilizar a `Closure` como um `callback`.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

1. Visto que não vou usar nada do contexto da instância atual da
   classe, poderíamos dizer que é mais performático utilizar a `static Closure`?
2. Ou a questão do `$this` ser "importado" para o escopo não significa
   perda de performasse (já que `$this` da `Closure` não recebe uma cópia, mas apenas criará a [**referencia da mesma instância**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.references.php) da classe atualmente invocada)?

Comment: Só para frisar: Nunca ouvi falar que a `Closure` poderia ser declarada como `static` (descobri a pouco tempo e descobri essas diferenças dando `print_r`) !Mas mais uma vez, como diz o @bigown,  o manual do PHP está falhando com seus usuários

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me surpreende que em uma destas situações é possível acessar o `$this`. Uma função estática jamais deveria ser capaz de fazer isto. Mas novamente, sabemos como os desenvolvedores da linguagem não pensam em tudo. Eles sabiam que isto não deveria ser aceito mas não perceberam que dava para contornar colocando a função estática dentro de uma função não estática.

Se não é algo documentado eu teria receio em usar. Só porque funciona não quer dizer que está certo. Nada garante que funcionará no futuro se não está documentado. Alguém certamente dirá que quem usa algo não documentado merece o que lhe acontecer no futuro se aquilo deixar de funcionar.

Então minha resposta oficial é **não use**.

Pra falar a verdade não sei se isto que você está fazendo faz algum sentido. Talvez por falta de contexto não seja fácil entender. Talvez seja eu.

A performance certamente não é relevante se você escolheu o PHP. Ela não é uma linguagem que tem essa qualidade. A diferença de fazer algo estático ou por instância será no máximo ínfima. Talvez nenhuma.

Eu questionaria se precisa colocar isto em uma classe. Só não o faço porque não entendi o problema por completo.

Em condições normais eu diria que uma função regular que não acessa nada da instância deveria ser declarada como estática, até para deixar claro que esta é a intenção. Mostrar no código o que deseja é mais importante do que a performance. Performance deve ser considerada somente se você mediu e viu que ela não está atendendo as necessidades. Note que não estou falando de *closure* aqui, já que *closure* estática não está documentada segundo o comentário do AP na pergunta.

Se a documentação dizer que pode usar uma *closure* estática fica o impasse se deveria ou não usar. Infelizmente estes questionamentos só poderiam ser feitos por quem tem autoridade, os desenvolvedores da linguagem. Mesmo assim eu só usaria se eles colocassem na documentação.

Comment: como curiosidade: recentemente fiz o uso de closure em uma função para filtro de dados e o acesso ao `$this` foi permitido na versão 5.4 do PHP "upei" os arquivos para o site que estava na versão 5.3 e não permitiu o acesso ao `$this` dentro da closure. Achei estanho.

Comment: Acho que passei uma informação errada na pergunta, bigown!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters conserte-a então.

Comment: @JohniDouglasMarangon a funcionalidade está disponível a partir da versão 5.4 >=

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48408/usar-static-closures-ou-closures-no-php), as finalidades que poderiam ser aplicadas utilizando `static` numa `Closure` seriam:

- Impedir que seja vinculada ao contexto (Classe) em que a mesma é chamada.

Exemplo:

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $func = static function() {
            var_dump($this);
        };
        $func();
    }
};
new Foo();
```

A saída seria:

> Notice: Undefined variable: this in %s on line %d

- Impedir a vinculação do `$this` da `Closure` a um objeto através da chamada do método `bindTo` (e provavelmente `Closure::bind` e `Closure::call`).

  ```
  $func = static function() {
      // function body
  };

  $func = $func->bindTo(new StdClass);

  $func();
  ```

Seria gerado um `E_WARNING`:

> Warning: Cannot bind an instance to a static closure in /in/sLLS9 on line 5

Fora isso, não há nada mais que a documentação detalhe, como por exmeplo, se isso implica em ganho de performance ou não,.

Comment: Esse link para documentação esta correto? A intenção seria mostrar os links da pergunta? Ou a intenção é este link especificamente http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static ?